# Transforming Individual Polygon Node Co-ordinates SQL Server 2008 (Spatial Geography)

Tags: sql-server-2008, loops, parsing, polygon, spatial

I have a set of polygons stored as Geography type within SQL Server 2008. My aim is to transform the co-ordinates of these polygons to a different projection.

I have a stored procedure which can transform a set of co-ordinates, but this can only convert individual points which have both an X and Y value.

Using WKT I have pulled the individual nodes from my polygons, and I then want to convert each of these nodes individually. I can then rebuild the WKT with my new transformed co-ordinates.

Does anybody know of a way to parse each of these individual nodes so that I can convert them one by one? My node string looks like this (individual points are separated by a comma, spaces separate the x and y values):

POLYGON ((113.26456971466541 23.094733481094721, 113.26615758240223 23.091891178768353, 113.27456898987293 23.095562474614567, 113.27557750046253 23.093292599234712, 113.27634997665882 23.09356893393959, 113.27379651367664 23.099440912063049, 113.27501960098743 23.102179435943992, 113.27381797134876 23.103023186104451, 113.27116794884205 23.100940939266334, 113.27231593430042 23.098562598885763, 113.27319569885731 23.096588840457258, 113.26798148453236 23.0943781965919, 113.26761670410633 23.095024616306429, 113.26671548187733 23.094624922040744, 113.26613612473011 23.095503260961348, 113.26456971466541 23.094733481094721))

Comment: Are you asking for a way to turn the well known text into a series of individual points?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.

Not exactly.I want to use my stored procedure to transform all of the individual points listed above (which I have pulled from the WKT). I am using a stored procedure to transform the points, but I need a way to parse these and convert them one by one.

Comment: So you need help to turn it from a single record of many points into n records with 1 point per record?

Answer (score 1):

I looks like a SQL cursor and a while loop to unspool the points in your polygon is what you're asking for

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReprojectPolygons]

AS
 DECLARE geography_cursor CURSOR
 FOR SELECT id, data FROM [MyPolygons] -- where [data] column contains geography data

 -- variables to store data cursor points to
 DECLARE @id INTEGER
 DECLARE @data sys.geography

 -- variables to loop through points in polygon
 DECLARE @pointcount INTEGER
 DECLARE @pointindex INTEGER
 DECLARE @point sys.geography

 -- result WKT from your reprojection
 DECLARE @result VARCHAR(MAX)

 OPEN geography_cursor

 FETCH NEXT FROM geography_cursor 
 INTO @id, @data

 -- loop through polygons    
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
    SET @pointcount = @data.STNumPoints()
    SET @pointindex = 1 
    SET @result = ''
    -- iterate points in polygon
    WHILE @pointindex <= @pointcount
    BEGIN
        SET @point = @data.STPointN(@pointindex)
        -- process point reprojection here by calling your stored procedure
        -- assuming you're passing the point as an OUTPUT parameter, this example continues using @point as the reprojected value
        if(@pointindex > 1)
            SET @result = @result + ','
        SET @result = @result + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @point.Long) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @point.Lat)
        SET @pointindex = @pointindex + 1
    END
    SET @result = 'POLYGON((' + @result + '))'
    -- do something with reprojected polygon WKT in @result
    FETCH NEXT FROM geography_cursor 
    INTO @id, @data
 END
 CLOSE geography_cursor
 DEALLOCATE geography_cursor
RETURN 0
```